# Libvirt does not list all supported CPU features

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I installed libvirt-bin on my Ubuntu Server 16.04. But the weird thing I found is that libvirt does not list all supported CPU features of the host.

When I open file /proc/cpuinfo, I can see 'aes' is in the flags list.

However, when I run 'virsh capabilities', I got result below, which shows host cpu does not have feature 'aes'.

```
<capabilities>

  <host>
    <uuid>30373237-3132-4d32-3236-30383034485a</uuid>
    <cpu>
      <arch>x86_64</arch>
      <model>SandyBridge</model>
      <vendor>Intel</vendor>
      <topology sockets='1' cores='10' threads='2'/>
      <feature name='invpcid'/>
      <feature name='erms'/>
      <feature name='bmi2'/>
      <feature name='smep'/>
      <feature name='avx2'/>
      <feature name='bmi1'/>
      <feature name='fsgsbase'/>
      <feature name='abm'/>
      <feature name='pdpe1gb'/>
      <feature name='rdrand'/>
      <feature name='f16c'/>
      <feature name='osxsave'/>
      <feature name='movbe'/>
      <feature name='dca'/>
      <feature name='pcid'/>
      <feature name='pdcm'/>
      <feature name='xtpr'/>
      <feature name='fma'/>
      <feature name='tm2'/>
      <feature name='est'/>
      <feature name='smx'/>
      <feature name='vmx'/>
      <feature name='ds_cpl'/>
      <feature name='monitor'/>
      <feature name='dtes64'/>
      <feature name='pbe'/>
      <feature name='tm'/>
      <feature name='ht'/>
      <feature name='ss'/>
      <feature name='acpi'/>
      <feature name='ds'/>
      <feature name='vme'/>
    </cpu>
...
```

Then I open file /usr/share/libvirt/cpu_map.xml, I can see CPU models below, which means Sandbridge inherit from Westmere, and it should have feature 'aes'.

```
<model name='Westmere'>
  <model name='Nehalem'/>
  <feature name='aes'/>
</model>

<model name='SandyBridge'>
  <model name='Westmere'/>
  <feature name='pclmuldq'/>
  <feature name='x2apic'/>
  <feature name='tsc-deadline'/>
  <feature name='xsave'/>
  <feature name='avx'/>
  <feature name='rdtscp'/>
</model>
```

I think the flags list in /proc/cpuinfo should be correct since it is generated by linux kernel calling cpuid. Is this a bug in libvirt, or 'aes' is just a subset of some listed features in the output of 'virsh capabilities' ?

More interesting thing is, after I start a guest, and login, I found that in guest os, 'aes' is in /proc/cpuinfo .

Any idea?

Thanks,
Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the libvirt CPU design, the CPU model name is treated as a short-cut/alias for a set of CPU features. So when you query the host CPU model in the capaibilities XML, you will see some CPU model which expresses the core set of features, and then a list of zero or more features that are not already part of the base CPU model listed. Your example, shows "SandyBridge" as the CPU model in the capabilities. This inherits from "Westmere", and "Westmere" is declared to include the "aes" feature. Thus libvirt does not need to list the "aes" feature in the capabilities - it only needs to list features that are *not* already part of the "SandyBridge" model.

If you want to see the fully expanded list of CPU features though, you can save the .... XML to a file CPUMODEL.xml and then call "virsh cpu-baseline --features CPUMODEL.xml".